# Python/ Django- forms.DateTimeField is restricting available values

Tags: python, django, forms, validation, user-input

I have a Python/ Django project, and on one of the forms, I am giving the user a 'date/time' field on which to select a date & time for a meeting.

The field definition in the form is written (in forms.py) with:

```
class presentationForm(ValidatedForm):
    ...
    presentation_date = mDateTimeField(required=False, widget=forms.DateTimeInput(format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M', attrs=({'class':'datetimepicker presentation_date', 'name':'presentation_date2'})))
    ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        budget = self.instance
        if hasattr(budget, 'id'):
            ...
            if budget.presentation_date:
                pres_meeting = budget.meeting or Meeting.objects.create(project=budget.project, purpost='7')
                ...
                if not budget.meeting:
                    budget.meeting = pres_meeting
                    budget.save()
                if not budget.meeting or not pres_meeting.date:
                    pres_meeting.date = budget.presentation_date
                    pres_meeting.save()
        else: self.presenters = []

        super(BudgetPresentationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['presentation_date'].widget.attrs.update({'data-meeting-id': getattr(self,'pres_meeting_id', ''), 'data-meeting-creator': getattr(self,'pres_meeting_creator', '')})

BudgetPresentationFormset = inlineformset_factory(Project, Budget, form= BudgetPresentationForm, max_num=30, extra=1, can_delete=False)
```

The problem that I'm having with the 'date/time' field on the form, is that although the user can scroll through the calendar that is displayed as a drop down when they click in the field (they can scroll as far back/ forward as they like), only the dates between 01/01/2015- 01/01/2017 are available for selection- all of the other dates before 01/01/2015, or after 01/01/2017 are 'greyed out' and it is not possible to select them.

Obviously, as it's now approaching the 01/01/2017, users need to be able to select dates beyond this in order to schedule future meetings.

If I right-click on `mDateTimeField`, and select 'Go To Definition', I am taken to a class definition (also in forms.py) which shows that `mDateTimeField` is defined with:

```
class mDateTimeField(forms.DateTimeField):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs.setdefault('input_formats', DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS)
    # kwargs.setdefault('localize', True)
    super(mDateTimeField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

so `mDateField` clearly inherits from `forms.DateTimeField`, but I can't see anywhere that a 'start_date', 'end_date' or 'max' or 'min' values are defined for the `presentation_date` variable... so why is it that the date values available for selection are restricted to dates from within the last two years?

Is there something I'm missing here?

**Edit**

If I right-click on `datetimepicker` on the line where `presentation_date` is being set to `mDateTimeField(...)`, and choose 'Go to definition', it takes me to a file called `jquery.datetimepicker.full.js`, which I can't see anywhere in my local directory, so I assume is a file from a library that's being used by the project?

Having Google'd this, it appears that the `datetimepicker` is a plugin available from https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker ... given that this is the case, can I fix the issue locally on my computer, or will I need to contact the developer to fix this?

Comment: Yeah, I thought it might be something set in the JavaScript- but there's no reference to `datetimepicker` in the template that's displaying this page (the template has both HTML & JavaScript written in it- but no reference to `datetimepicker` in either...)

Comment: There is a reference to `datetimepicker` in the Python class definition of the form that displays this field (the class is defined in forms.py), which is in the first block of code that I've quoted in my OP.

Comment: It appears that the `datetimepicker` is a jQuery plugin available on GitHub (https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker)... If this is the case, can I fix the problem locally on my machine, or will I need to contact the developer to fix it?